# How to change innerHTML content such as(input field names,ids,onclick) attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to copy all content of a div into another div, but before copying I need to change all input fields names and ids. See the code below.

```
 <div id="first_div">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <select name="marital_status" id="marital_status">
        <option value="1" selected='selected'>Select</option>
        <option value="2">Single</option>
        <option value="3">Married</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 <div id="second_div">
 </div>
```

Now I want to copy content of first_div into second_div,but before copying I need to change input field firstname into last_name, how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I see you tagged jQuery in the question, you could use jQuery clone method to get started quickly : https://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
var clone = $("#first_div").clone();
```

then modifying the clone innerHTML like so

```
clone.find("#firstname").attr("id", "lastname"); // modifying div id
// do the same for every element you want to modify id, etc
//then finally append it to the second_div
$("#second_div").html(clone.html());
```

Comment: It should be appended to #second_div

Comment: Indeed  I've firstly misunderstood OP expectations, so I approved the edit.

Comment: thanks that works fine. but how can i add onchange event handler for that befor copying?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vanilla Javascript version:

```
var clone = document.getElementById('first_div').cloneNode(true);
clone.querySelector('#firstname').id = 'lastname';

document.getElementById('second_div').innerHTML = clone.innerHTML;
```

If you don't have jQuery added to your solution, it would be good to not add it at all, if only using for that.

Comment: @SumanBogati thanks for the comment, I have updated the code =)

Answer (score 0):

By using pure javaScript

```
 var fdiv = document.getElementById("first_div");
 var clnNode = fdiv.cloneNode(true);

 var clnInput = clnNode.querySelector('#firstname');
 clnInput.setAttribute('id', 'lastname')

 var secDiv = document.getElementById('second_div')
 secDiv.innerHTML = clnNode.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the inner html and replace the id:

```js
var html = document.getElementById('first_div').innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/firstname/g, 'last_name');
document.getElementById('second_div').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="first_div">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
  <select name="marital_status" id="marital_status">
    <option value="1" selected='selected'>Select</option>
    <option value="2">Single</option>
    <option value="3">Married</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="second_div">
</div>
```